# Help linking External Storage for bitcoin data using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bitcoin-core, raspberry-pi

I mounted my external disk to wrong directory (wanted it to be ~/bitcoinData) , instead ended up creating a directory on SD card ( /home/pi/bitcoinData ) and now SD card (root) is full. i cannot seem to delete SD card bitcoinData directory (permission denied). how do i fix this? and link hdd to correct directory?

Comment: Pass `-datadir=/path/to/folder/` in the command line when starting bitcoind.

Comment: For a change in the directory, I agree with @UgamKamat but I think the problem not is correlated with bitcoin core but the permission user in your raspberry pi. try a command to the terminal with `sudo rm -r path/bitcoin`

Comment: i have resolved this, i believe it was a user permissions issue. thanks

Comment: @gaiameta if you post a well-written answer with steps to solve it could help others and earn you addition rep on this site.